# Little box where I could write in

Tags: javascript

I would need to use a little textbox in order to write in and to get the value but without creating a window. (In which I would have created a textbox element)
I would need something like the alert box but I would like to write in.
Do you know what I could use ?

Comment: Whats wrong with adding `<textarea>`/`<input type="text">` someWhere in DOM?

Comment: You want alert box without creating a window! I don't get it.

Comment: I guess you're looking for something like lightbox.

Comment: Something like the jQuery UI Dialog?  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 3):

To get an dialog box with input using javascript you can use `window.prompt`, look for more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.prompt).

If you want something prettier go for a modal window. There are plenty plugins for jQuery (and there should be enough scripts available in vanilla JS as well) to achieve this.